# How do we prevent air in the water lines from our well?

Tags: plumbing, leak, well

We receive our water from a spring fed well. There is approximately 125 feet of pipe from house to spring house. We have obvious air in our line. We have replaced 2 check valves and foot valve as well as checked for obvious leaks in house. The pump does not run continuously. Pressure is maintained in our pressure tank. Water sprays from the faucet when turned on and pipes rattle loudly when toilet is flushed. How do we find leak without digging up 125 feet of pipe.

Comment: A diagram or photo of the pump house fixtures and tank would do wonders.  Lacking that, have you tried bleeding some of the air out of the tank?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a shallow well pump.  I would start looking from the pump to your well. This is where you will get air sucked into the water without having a water leak.  Tighten all the hose clamps, you may need to add thread sealant to primer plug or any threaded fittings.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime during a dry spell walk along the buried line with a temperature detector gun. There should be a cooler wet spot where the leak is.